# class java.lang.String (substring) boolean/ if statement error

Tags: string, substring

I'm wondering how you can put a Class `java.lang.String` (substring) into an if statement. What I'm looking for is using the if statement in finding the characters that are included.

Since the name "Aaliyah" is from index 0-6, I'm wondering how can you put the boolean statement in finding two letters. The 1st letter I want it to find the "A" and the 2nd letter is to find the "h".

```
String name = "Aaliyah";

System.out.print(name.substring(0,1));
System.out.println(name.substring(6));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it. I've gone ahead and updated most of the formatting.

Comment: I can't see any if statement, edit your question and post your code